# Interleave a shared flow and non-blocking channel in Kotlin at specific points

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-sharedflow

I have a SharedFlow and I want to interleave items from the non-blocking channel in a specific frequency.

```
(input / hot) Flow -> A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, ...

Channel -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...

Output flow -> A, B, C, 1, D, E, F, 2, G, H, I, 3, ... (if channel has items)
Output flow -> A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, ... (if channel has no items)
Output flow -> A, B, C, D, 1, E, F, G, 2, H, I, ... (if 1 comes just after D)
```

Key is that, its important to space 1, 2, 3 at regular intervals and skipped if Channel subsequently stops producing values.

I can change the channel to be a StateFlow as well. What is the idiomatic way to implement this with Kotlin flows?

Comment: What if `1` happens straight after `D`? Should it be emitted immediately or after `F`?

Comment: @broot yes it should come after D, will edit question